# Disable C1E of GA-870A-USB3 AMD FX-6300 hw config

Tags: kernel, bios, acpi, amd-processor

```
My Ubuntu box is:
Mobo: Gigabyte GA-870A-USB3
Chipset:North Bridge:AMD 870, South Bridge AMD SB850
CPU: AMD Phenom II X2 560
RAM: Kingmax DDR3 1333MHz 4*4GByte
Display card: Asus EAH5450 Silent/DI/512MD2/LP-HD5450

BIOS:PnP 1.0a, DMI 2.0, SMBIOS 2.4 ACPI 1.0b  and AWARD licenced
Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-47-generic 
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
```

Everything was perfect for about 8 years long until now
when I changed the CPU to AMD FX-6300.

I upgraded my BIOS to F5h version according to the manufacturer
https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-870A-USB3-rev-31#support-cpu

The new F5h version of BIOS and the old Phenom CPU could work with
the above Linux perfectly.

But when CPU was changed to FX-6300 and I used the safety default in the CMOS, only the GRUB could started and its menu was OK, but the kernel was frozen even if I tried to use some command line kernel parameter (`acpi=off nolapic`) in grub menu.
So I couldn't start the kernel with the new FX-6300 CPU at all,
until I turned off `C1E` option in the BIOS according to the
second workaround of this (old dated 2012) bug report:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1007508

I put some file on this link (my google drive)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Nms5D2rYTeGOipoNmWSY1w5FvqaCynyN

Two files from journal of systemd:

```
1 Unable_to_Boot_acpi_off_nolapic_C1E_enabled
2 Able_to_Boot_C1E_disabled
```

And output of

```
dmidecode
lshw
lspci
/proc/cpuinfo
```

(My second experiment was installing win 7 onto the second part of an SSD 
and it worked perfectly with enabled C1E.)

Even though I have read something about the DMI, SMBIOS
can somebody tell me what can be the root problem?
As I see Gigabyte has finished the BIOS update for this mobo at 2013,
is there any possibility for a more compatible kernel version?

And especially I would interest what are the disadvanteges of this workaround
of disabling the C1E in BIOS ??

I would like to know whether, despite the disadvantages, if I would stay
with the new CPU fx-6300.

Comment: Suggestion: Reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It is true that the above Linux was installed with the old Phenom II X2 CPU. But we need to know when I installed Ubuntu again with FX-6300 new CPU, I would have to disable the C1E during the installation because the install wizard can run also only in this way.